# jQuery slider re-positions when tabbing through content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wcag

When tabbing through linked content within a jquery slider, the slide position jumps to the link in :focus, breaking the alignment of the slides. Standard keyboard navigation is important to me for accessibility purposes.

fairly in-experienced jquery coder sorry.

what I am trying to get working is

```
if($('.item.one h3 a').is(':focus') || $('.item.one').position().left > 620){
$(this).find('.item.one').position().left = 0;
};
```

Comment: Your code looks good, but a fiddle would help understanding your problem